# Show that for any Borel set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and nonnegative number $t<\mu(A)$ there exists a borel set $B\subset A$ for which $\mu(B)=t$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be non-negative $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$ that equals $0$ on singletons. Show that for any Borel set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and nonnegative number $t<\mu(A)$ there exists a borel set $B\subset A$ for which $\mu(B)=t$.

---

When $t=0$ we take $B=\emptyset$.

Any **hint** how to deal with the case $t>0$?

**(I do not want the full answer as for now, please)**

Answer (score 1):

Hint: To keep it simple assume $\mu(A)<\infty$, and consider the function $f(x):=\mu(A\cap(-\infty,x])$. Keywords: Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: thanks, but how do we know that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: You've assumed that $\mu$ puts $0$ mass on singletons.

Comment: How it makes $f$ continuous? I can't see that... Could you elaborate please?