# Showing there exists ray that splits Borel set in half

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ without atoms. Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel set with $\mu(E) > 0$. I want to show there exists $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu(E \cap (-\infty, t)) = \frac{\mu(E)}{2}$. This question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2500262/if-e-is-a-borel-measurable-set-show-that-there-exists-a-subset-of-e-with-ha) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471880/show-that-for-any-borel-set-a-subset-mathbbr-and-nonnegative-number-t-mua), so I'm primarily asking for a verification of my proof and also to a point out a concern with my proof.

The standard method is to prove that $f(t) =  \mu(E \cap (-\infty, t)) $ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. We first observe that we can write
$$ f(t) = \int \chi_{E \cap (-\infty, t)} d\mu. $$
Fix $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and let $(t_n)$ be any sequence converging to $t_0$. There exists $M > 0$ such that $|t_n| \leq M$ for all $n$. This means we have $ \chi_{E \cap (-\infty, t_n)} \leq \chi_{E \cap (-\infty, M)} $. Furthermore, we have
$$ \int \chi_{E \cap (-\infty, M)} d\mu = \mu(E \cap (-\infty, M)) \leq 1 < \infty, $$
so the dominating function is in $L^1(\mu)$. So by the dominated convergence theorem, we have
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int \chi_{E \cap (-\infty, t_n)}d\mu = \int \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \chi_{E \cap (-\infty, t_n)}d\mu = \int \chi_{E \cap (-\infty, t_0)}d\mu$$
i.e. $f(t_n) \rightarrow f(t_0)$. This proves continuity of $f$, and to complete the proof of the main problem, we apply intermediate value theorem after showing $f$ tends to $0$ and $\mu(E)$ to the left and right, respectively.

My main concern is that I never used that $\mu$ has no atoms. Did I make a mistake in my proof, or did I somehow use it implicitly in the proof?

Comment: consider a measure which is concentrated in three points having measure $1/3$ each, and check whether your proof still works.

Comment: Your use of the dominated convergence theorem seems faulty. Why do you claim the indicator function of $E\cap (-\infty, t_n)$ converges to the indicator function of $E \cap (-\infty, t_0)$? It makes more sense to use continuity of probability to consider situations where either $t_n\searrow t_0$ or $t_n\nearrow t_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an example, let $A_n = (-\infty, 1/n)$. Your proof claims that $\lim \chi_{A_n} = \lim \chi_{(-\infty, 0)}$ pointwise. However, this is not the case; you need to use the fact that $\mu$ has no atoms to handle cases like this.